# How does Fortran deallocate linked lists?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, linked-list, fortran

I would like to use linked lists in Fortran to hold an array of data of an undefined length.

I have the following setup:

```
TYPE linked_list
    INTEGER :: data
    TYPE(linked_list) :: next_item => NULL()
END TYPE
```

Now say I create such a list:

```
TYPE(LINKED_LIST) :: example_list
example_list%data =1
ALLOCATE(example_list%next_item)
example_list%next_item%data = 2
ALLOCATE(example_list%next_item%next_item)
example_list%next_item%next_item%data = 3
```

My question is, if I perform:

```
DEALLOCATE(example_list)
```

will all the nested levels also be deallocated or do I need to traverse the list to the deepest element and deallocate from the deepest element upward?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did this in Fortran, but I'm pretty sure you have to deallocate manually. If you just deallocate the head, then you'll lose the reference and have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes. I was quite afraid of that. I must say though, I'm having trouble, what's the phrase, rolling my own garbage collection?

Comment: You can't implement memory managed fortran.

Comment: Is that sarcasm or a statement of fact?

Comment: @emiller: It's a statement of fact. You could, technically, create your own memory manager object, and then pass through this object to allocate every type, so that it keeps track of all allocations, but you still have no way to let the code know when something dynamically allocated falls out of scope and cannot be reached anymore. In non-memory managed languages, you normally use reference counting to compensate, and you are free to use such pattern, but that would mean to make things really complicated for the average fortran programmer.

Comment: @emiller Keep all your arrays allocatable. Pair each allocate statement with a deallocate statement. Use pointers only when necessary or very convenient. If you follow these three, you will be fine. Fortran forces you to keep track of your memory, which I really appreciate about Fortran - it discourages lazy programming, and makes you know your program better. Great question and answer though.

Comment: @IRO-bot: _don't_ keep all your arrays allocatable. Keep them pointers. Allocatable can be a trap if you don't understand its semantics: they are automatically deallocated once they get out of scope. In Types, you may not have problems, but never assume that you can transfer memory allocated to a client code in a subroutine which has an allocatable declaration for that memory. lack of memory management is the source of tragic errors and a lot of boilerplate code. It's not about lazy programming, it's about having to take care of stuff you are not supposed to take care of in the first place.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Sorry, cannot agree with any of that ^. Have a good day! :)

Comment: @IRO-bot: You may not agree, but 95% of programmers agree on what I said, and big research has been invested in doing proper and automatic memory management. Now, you are of course welcome to imply that everyone that did research on that regard is incompetent...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to deallocate each node manually. This is where "Object oriented" like style comes useful.

```
module LinkedListModule
    implicit none
    private

    public :: LinkedListType
    public :: New, Delete
    public :: Append

    interface New
        module procedure NewImpl
    end interface

    interface Delete
        module procedure DeleteImpl
    end interface

    interface Append
        module procedure AppendImpl
    end interface

    type LinkedListType
        type(LinkedListEntryType), pointer :: first => null()
    end type

    type LinkedListEntryType
        integer :: data
        type(LinkedListEntryType), pointer :: next => null()
    end type

contains

    subroutine NewImpl(self)
        type(LinkedListType), intent(out) :: self

        nullify(self%first) 
    end subroutine

    subroutine DeleteImpl(self)
       type(LinkedListType), intent(inout) :: self

       if (.not. associated(self%first)) return

       current => self%first
       next => current%next
       do
           deallocate(current)
           if (.not. associated(next)) exit
           current => next
           next => current%next
       enddo

    end subroutine

    subroutine AppendImpl(self, value)

       if (.not. associated(self%first)) then
           allocate(self%first)
           nullify(self%first%next)
           self%first%value = value
           return
       endif


       current => self%first
       do
           if (associated(current%next)) then
               current => current%next
           else
             allocate(current%next)
             current => current%next
             nullify(current%next)
             current%value = value
             exit
           endif
       enddo

    end subroutine

end module
```

Beware: it's past midnight and I'm not really fond of coding in a browser window. This code may not work. It's just a layout.

Use like this

```
program foo
   use LinkedListModule
   type(LinkedListType) :: list

   call New(list)
   call Append(list, 3)
   call Delete(list)
end program
```

Comment: Bingo. The DeleteImpl method is exactly what I was looking for. How nice and neat this object oriented fortran is.

Comment: @emiller: It's not object oriented. It's object oriented style.

Comment: `Append` sweeps through the whole list, from the head to the tail, so it is very inefficient. It is better to keep track of the tail node and to append the new node to it.

Why distinguishing `LinkedListType` from `LinkedListEntryType`?